# What is $\exp(i\pi J_2) |jm\rangle$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $|jm\rangle,m=-j,-j+1,...,j-1,j$ be the standard (unique up to a phase choice) orthonormal basis of the $d=(2j+1)$-dim complex "unitary" irrep $u: \text{su}(2)\rightarrow \text{gl}(V)$ of Lie algebra $\text{su}(2)$, i.e., $u(X)^* =-u(X)$. Then what is $\exp(i\pi J_2) |jm\rangle$? where $J_2 = u(\sigma_2/2)$ and $\sigma_2$ is the standard Pauli matrix (with slight abuse of notation, I am also using $u$ to denote its complexification).

I asked this in [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509618/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compute-exp-i-pi-j-2-jm-rangle-1j-m-j-m-r/530632#530632) and provided an incomplete answer, where I was able to prove that
$$
\exp(i\pi J_2) |jm\rangle = \pm (-1)^{j-m}|j,-m\rangle
$$
However, I can't figure out whether it should be $+$ or $-$.

**EDIT**:
$|jm\rangle,m=-j,-j+1,...,j-1,j$ is the unique (up to phase choice) orthonormal basis such that

\begin{align}
J_3 |jm\rangle &=m|jm\rangle \\
J_{\pm} |jm\rangle &= \sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m\pm 1)} |j,m\pm1\rangle
\end{align}

**EDIT 2**: In [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509618/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compute-exp-i-pi-j-2-jm-rangle-1j-m-j-m-r/530632#530632), I added a note that we can use the property of characters to show that if $j=l$ is an integer, then we must have $+1$, so my guess for half-integers $j=s$, we should have $+1$ since that it the case for $j=1/2$, though I'm not sure of the details for general half-integer $j=s$.

**EDIT 3**: (After a year or so) In [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509618/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compute-exp-i-pi-j-2-jm-rangle-1j-m-j-m-r/530632#530632), I have provided a complete solution showing that
$$
\exp(i\pi J_2) |jm\rangle = (-1)^{j-m}|j,-m\rangle
$$
The main idea is that for $j=1/2$, we can show that it has $+$ and for all integer $j$, we have $+$. Now if $j$ is a half-integer and $V_j$ is the corresponding irrep, then
$$
V_j \otimes V_{1/2} = V_{j+1/2} \oplus V_{j-1/2}
$$
And the rest follows from this decomposition (see link for more detail).